# How to stop a while loop to get input from user using Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, while-loop, user-input

it is incredible how the knowledge of something so basic can be buried in a so hard to find place. I have spent close to a month googling for an answer--watching videos, reading documents, books, etc--of how to stop a while loop to get input from an user using Tkinter.

My code below is looping twice and leaving the loop before I am able to provide an input!!!

Anyway, theory is appreciated, but a sample code will be of greater help. Thank you very, very much indeed.

```
# Python 3.5.1
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

loop = 0

while loop < 2:

    print ('loop')

    def user_data():
        user_input = data.get()
        print (user_input)

    lb=ttk.Label(root, text="Enter data")
    data=ttk.Entry(root)
    bt=ttk.Button(root, text='Ok', command=user_data)

    lb.grid(row=0, column=1)
    data.grid(row=0, column=2)
    bt.grid(row=0, column=3)

    loop += 1

print ('left loop')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where are you defining `root`?

Comment: This is hard to do because this simply isn't how graphical user interfaces are designed to work. It's a bit like saying you've searched for a month on how to cook steak in a blender. If you need to pause and get information from a user, you should be using a modal dialog. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Comment: Good one, Bryan.  Steak in a blender.  It took me almost five months to research that one!

Comment: @ Hobbes, I am defining 'root' right above 'loop = 0', just forgot to past it.

Comment: @Bryan, unless dialog windows are more powerful than what I can see, I don't think it is a workable solution to a form that will require seven input/entry boxes in a single row with the option to add n number of rows. I am new to Python, but as far as I could see, input(), for instance, stops a program/loop until a user provides some data. The problem with input() is that I only saw it working in the shell, not in a GUI.

Comment: Have you read http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm? Does it help?

Comment: @Veky, yes, I did read the effbot... article, but it does not seem to help. Opening a single dialog window is already one too many for the kind of procedure that the user needs to perform. If the

Comment: Then sorry, you'll have to be more precise. Can you tell a story of what you expect to happen: what the user presses, clicks, how much they wait, what happens in response and so on. So far, all I know is that you want to pause the loop until user inputs something, and a (modal) dialog seemed the most natural solution.

Comment: ops... @Veky, do you guys think that dialog window works for multiple consecutive entries? Would its use imply in the user having to be opening and closing multiple dialog windows throughout the recording of each transaction?

Comment: Modal dialogs can be as powerful as you want -- there is no limit to what you can do in a modal dialog. Though, typically they are for relatively simple forms. You can certainly create a dialog with seven entry boxes in a row, with the ability to add more. That is not what you asked about, however. You asked about how to wait for exactly two items, and the way to wait for input in a GUI is a modal dialog. Do you really want to create a GUI that opens a window to wait for input, or is what you're describing the actual GUI you're trying to create? Your real requirements are very unclear.

Comment: Up till now you haven't mentioned anything about transactions. This is leading nowhere. Please specify what behavior you want. If you read your "question" again, you'll probably see it's incredibly vague.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand how GUIs work. Generally speaking, they are _always_ waiting for user input. You don't need to add an extra wait. You simply set up the GUI, and then the GUI responds to events such as the user entering data, clicking a button, etc. Is that what you're trying to do? What do you expect to happen after the user enters the data?

Comment: @Veky, I tried to shorten the example and go straight to my problem. If more info is needed... I need a user to enter x amount. Then the amount can be divided into different categories, lets say different groups of expenses. For each category (expense), several entries per row will be required (amount, purpose, beneficiary, mean of payment, etc). To complete the operation, the sum of the categories should add up to the x amount first provided.

Comment: @Bryan, the data from the user will be stored in a database. I am trying to create a small and simple, but customized, accounting system.

Comment: Is the set of entries the _only_ part of the GUI, or are there other parts? ie: do you have a single window with a bunch of entries and a "save" button, or do you have some other sort of main window (maybe a list of transactions/), and then open a dialog to let users enter more data?

Comment: @Bryan, that is exactly what I was expecting, the GUI to wait for the user input. Why doesn't the loop stop at the Entry widget?

Comment: @Bryan, I just need one window. The set of entries are all what I need. Get the info and store in the database.

Comment: @Bryan, I have already figured out how to do many other things, including provide a drop-down list with data from the database using combobox.

Comment: Then, it sounds like you don't need to wait for input. Like I said earlier, GUIs are in a perpetual state of waiting already. You just need to create a regular GUI and add a "Save" button.

Comment: The loop doesn't stop at widgets. All the widgets are redrawn and all the input events (pressed keys, for example) are processed in _every_ iteration of the loop. You can nudge the user by putting the cursor inside Entry widget, but they can type "5" to add "5" at the place of the cursor, or they can type "Tab" to go to some other control. Tk doesn't care.

Comment: @Bryan, I already have the "save" button. Are you suggesting that I should not have a loop? What other option could allow for the user to split the x mount into n number of different categories?

Comment: @Veky, okay. Putting the cursor inside the Entry widget seems to be a plausible solution. Do you have a sample code to share?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626406/setting-focus-to-specific-tkinter-entry-widget is not hard. But I have a feeling it won't satisfy you. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316707/pause-for-an-event-in-python-tkinter will help.

Comment: @Veky, thanks for your help so far. Even though I haven't found the solution yet, I very much appreciate your attitude. You are a serious person that reflects on problems. I tried the focus and it didn't stop the loop. At a first glance, the callback example does not seem capable of offering the user the option of making choices like a while loop does. I will check it out more carefully. I am perplexed of how two basic elements of programming like while loop and user's input are not easily coming together in Tkinter.

Comment: @Veky, as I said before, input() does exactly what I need. It stops the while loop to wait for a user's input, even if I stick it in the code that I presented above. The problem is that the prompt for the user to provide the data pops up in the shell. Is there a way to combine input() and Tkinter Entry widget?

Comment: Well, input() is nice because it delegates its work to stdin.readline(), which does all the dirty work of blocking the call, reading the keyboard, writing the characters on the screen, handling Backspace and Enter, stripping final newline, and giving you a nice string at the end. It does so at the expense of blocking everything else the program is doing. You can't calculate something while you're waiting on input, but graphic apps need to handle all their events by themselves. It's not impossible to emulate input() there, but it goes against basic principles of GUI programming. :-/

Comment: Also, your main problem, reason why you have all these problems, seems to be that you want _one_ Entry widget to serve multiple purposes, and populate different variables at different times. That's hard to do even with input() - naturally you have different rows of the screen devoted to collecting different data, right? :-) [Added afterwards: I see somebody else has identified your main problem too, and answered your question. That's nice to hear.:]

Comment: @Veky, I very much appreciate all the help and I don't want to take more of you guys time. I am proceeding with the leads that you guys have provided until I can find a better solution or change the GUI or the programming language. Unfortunately, my main question remains unanswered. Rephrasing it (forget all my problems): How to use While Loop with Tkinter? In the end all programs end up running with the help of a GUI, right? And isn't While Loop a basic logical procedure used in programming? If so, shouldn't Tkinter have a way of handling While Loop? Again, thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Yes, all (modern) programs do run in a GUI, but the event loop of e.g. IDLE is completely separate from the loops in the code of the program IDLE is currently executing. Try it: while your program is waiting on an input(), you can resize the window, move it, even change some options, open find/replace dialog (and even replace some text:) and so on. From the perspective of OS, those are just two different processes. When you write your own GUI, the same process is doing all these things, and things clash. You get a much greater flexibility at the expense of basic stdio primitives not working.

Comment: You can use while loop in Tkinter without problems. What you cannot do (not easily, anyway) is block your main execution until a user presses some button, while at the same time allowing that user to do many other things with your program. (You also cannot, or at least it looks weird, use the same widget for different data variables entry, but that's minor.) This isn't insurmountable, and in fact Python has recently got a way (async/await) to program in such a way, where you can block a coroutine without blocking an entire program. However, tkinter still hasn't been rewritten to use this. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think the joke is on me after all. :-) I spent last three days telling you this can't be done easily, and it turns out I was wrong.

I'll give you the code soon, just let me explain where I went wrong. While I was writing my last comment, the main thing I wanted to explain to you is that when you run a console Python program inside a GUI console, those are two different processes, and the event loop of a GUI has nothing to do with how the inner Python program works.

In a GUI application, it breaks down since there is just one process, and its event loop cannot at the same time run (being responsive to normal app events like repainting a window or handling clicks/keypresses) and stay blocked (wait for you to click a button). It occured to me the things would be very simple if tkinter would enable the user to make additional event loops. It's not unreasonable: since tkinter already constructs one for its own purposes, it just needs to expose that constructor (or some other means of construction) to the user. And there won't be any GIL problems, since the other event loop just stays blocked (only one is actually executing).

Once I knew what I was searching, it wasn't so hard to find: you construct a Tk variable (of any type, Boolean works nice for this semantics), toggle its value, and toggle it back in the callback. In the meantime you wait for it to change. Easy as pie. :-)

I tried to change your code as little as possible, but of course, once you know the mechanism, you can do it much more nicely. I hope I've returned your faith in tkinter. :-)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
loop = 0
block = BooleanVar(root, False)

while loop < 2:

    print ('loop')

    def user_data():
        user_input = data.get()
        print (user_input)
        block.set(False)

    lb=ttk.Label(root, text="Enter data")
    data=ttk.Entry(root)
    bt=ttk.Button(root, text='Ok', command=user_data)

    lb.grid(row=0, column=1)
    data.grid(row=0, column=2)
    bt.grid(row=0, column=3)

    block.set(True)
    root.wait_variable(block)
    loop += 1

print ('left loop')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just a comment: of course, I still think this isn't how normal GUI applications should work. @Bryan Oakley has solved your X. I hope I have solved your Y. (See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem for terminology.) And I think it was an interesting and educational experience. :-)

Comment: @ Veky, GREAT!!! I know stackoverflow asks not to be saying thanks here, but I where else to do it.

Comment: Just accept the answer if it answers your question. :)

Comment: The answer hit the bullseye. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm... Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of discussion, it appears that you don't actually need to wait for anything. A GUI is in a perpetual state of waiting for events, so you don't need to add additional waiting. All you need is a "save" button, and a way for the user to input a variable number of values.

To allow the user to enter multiple values, you can add a button that adds more entry widgets. The only real trick is to keep a list of the entry widgets so that you can get the values out later in your program.

The following is a working example that illustrates the technique.

Note: This is not how I would actually do this in a real GUI because it relies on global variables. The point is to illustrate the general principle of dynamically adding entry widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk

def add_entry():
    """
    Add two entries, one for a description, one for an amount,
    along with some labels
    """
    # create the label and entry widgets
    label1 = tk.Label(entry_frame, text="Description:")
    label2 = tk.Label(entry_frame, text="Amount:")
    entry1 = tk.Entry(entry_frame)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(entry_frame)

    # lay them out on the screen
    column, row = entry_frame.grid_size()
    label1.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky="e", pady=2)
    entry1.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky="ew", pady=2, padx=4)
    label2.grid(row=row, column=2, sticky="e", pady=2)
    entry2.grid(row=row, column=3, sticky="ew", pady=2, padx=4)
    entry_frame.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=0)
    entry_frame.grid_rowconfigure(row+1, weight=1)

    # save the entries, so we can retrieve the values
    entries.append((entry1, entry2))

    # give focus to the new entry widget
    entry1.focus_set()

def save():
    # iterate over the entries, printing the values
    for description_entry, value_entry in entries:
        print("description: %s value: %s" % 
              (description_entry.get(), value_entry.get()))

# this is our global list of entries
entries = []

# create the main window and buttons
root = tk.Tk()

entry_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)

entry_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
button_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

add_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="add another entry", command=add_entry)
save_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Save", command=save)

add_button.pack(side="left")
save_button.pack(side="right")

# create the first entry
add_entry()

# start the main loop -- this is where the GUI starts waiting,
# and why you don't need to add your own loop.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It might be a path to what I need, I will dive deep into your example to try to make it fit my need. Somewhere, I will need to check if the figures of the categories add up to the total amount. If I can do this using "if", I should be safe. Otherwise, I will probably be back to the "while loop" problem.