# iterate through a list and get user response to each item using tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am being particularly obtuse. I am iterating through a list of technical italian words and wanting to insert a translation using a tkinter interface. There is no problem doing this without the GUI: My problem is that I cannot figure out how to do an iteration, load a word into a ttk.Label and wait for a user entry in a ttk.Entry field. I have searched and found explanations, but I am at a loss how to apply the suggestions. This is my code using a trivial list of words:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

def formd():

    list_of_terms = ['aardvark', 'ant','zombie', 'cat', 'dog', 'buffalo','eagle', 'owl','caterpiller', 'zebra',  'orchid','arum lily' ]
    discard_list = []
    temp_dict={}
    list_of_terms.sort()

    for item in list_of_terms:
        listKey.set(item)

    # need to wait and get user input
        translation =dictValue.get()
        temp_dict[item]=translation
        discard_list.append(item)
    # check if it has worked
    for key, value in temp_dict.items():
        print(key, value) 
# GUI for dict from list
LARGE_FONT= ("Comic sans MS", 12)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Nautical Term Bilingual Dictionary')
ttk.Style().configure("mybtn.TButton", font = ('Comic sans MS','12'), padding = 1,  foreground = 'DodgerBlue4')
ttk.Style().configure('red.TButton', foreground='red', padding=6, font=('Comic sans MS',' 10'))
ttk.Style().configure('action.TLabelframe', foreground = 'dodger blue3')
#.......contents frames.....................
nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
page5 = ttk.Frame(nb)
# declare variables
listKey= tk.StringVar()
dictValue = tk.StringVar()
# widgets
keyLabel =ttk.Label( page5, text = "key from list", font=LARGE_FONT).grid(row=3, column = 0)
Keyfromlist =ttk.Label(page5, width = 10, textvariable = listKey).grid(row = 3, column = 1)

valueLabel =ttk.Label( page5, text = "enter translation", font=LARGE_FONT).grid(row=3, column = 2)
listValue =ttk.Entry(page5, textvariable =dictValue, width = 15).grid(row = 3, column = 3)
#listValue.delete(0,'end')
#listValue.focus_set()

# add buttons
b1 = ttk.Button(page5, text="add to dictionary",style = "mybtn.TButton", command = formd)
b1.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
b5 = ttk.Button(page5, text="clear entry", style ="mybtn.TButton")
b5.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
nb.add(page5, text='From List')

nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")   

for child in root.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx =5, pady=5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

I wonder whether someone could take the time to suggest a solution, please. [How to stop a while loop to get input from user using Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983322/how-to-stop-a-while-loop-to-get-input-from-user-using-tkinter) was the one suggestion that I cannot figure how to use in my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tkinter doesn't *"play nice"* with `while` loops.

Fortunately for you, you don't need to use one.

You can do something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.list = ['aardvark', 'ant','zombie', 'cat', 'dog', 'buffalo','eagle', 'owl','caterpiller', 'zebra',  'orchid','arum lily' ]
        self.text = Label(self.root, text="aardvark")
        self.entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Ok", command=self.command)
        self.text.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button.pack()
    def command(self):
        print(self.text.cget("text")+" - "+self.entry.get())
        try:
            self.text.configure(text = self.list[self.list.index(self.text.cget("text"))+1])
        except IndexError:
            self.entry.destroy()
            self.button.destroy()
            self.text.configure(text = "You have completed the test")

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This essentially uses the `Button` widget to iterate to the next text and get the next input.